# Apache Synapse/WSO2 API No response

Tags: api, rest, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I want to send a query to the database and return the result to the client using WSO2 rest api. Here is the synapse config:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RestDBLookup" context="/dblookup">
   <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/channel/{name}" protocol="http">
      <inSequence>
         <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <password>pass</password>
                  <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL</url>
                  <user>user</user>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>SELECT ID, CHANNEL_NAME FROM CHANNEL where CHANNEL_NAME = ?</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('uri.var.name')" type="VARCHAR"/>
               <result name="channel_id" column="ID"/>
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ID" expression="get-property('channel_id')"/>
            <property name="State" value="after db"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

When I call the url `http://localhost:8280/dblookup/channel/someChannel` with rest client I get the log after the dblookup

```
LogMediator ID = 40810162, State = after db
```

but the `outSequence` is not executed and I only get Status 202 Accepted on the rest client with no body.

So the question is how can I construct some response (in JSON format for example) and send it to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synapse mediation has three flows:

- inSequence - handle in coming request and define how request
  should be processed (mediate) before send to target endpoint
- outSequence - handle response coming back from endpoint and define how response should be processed (mediate) before send to client
- faultSequence - if error occurred during service mediation, then fault message hand-over to fault sequence. You can write down logic in fault sequence based on your requirement (log error, drop message and send back fault).

Now let's see your use-case. What you trying to do is query database in  inSequence. Also you getting result as well. But problem is result not send back to client. Here problem was the mediation you written in inSequence not calling the outSequence. Therefore outSequence not getting hit. For an example if you call backend service in inSequence, then response hit to outSequence. In your case response come back to inSequence. Therefore we can do either one of following option:

1. Adding `<loopback/>` mediator after `</log>` mediator in inSequence.
   This will move message from inSequence to outSequence.
2. Move logic written in outSequence to inSequence. Then add
   `<respond/>` at the end of inSequence. This will send current
   message back to client. So you may not need to have outSequence.

Hope above answer helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As Indika suggested I used `<respond/>` and ended up with this configuration:

```
<api context="/dblookup" name="RestDBLookup" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="POST GET" protocol="http" uri-template="/channel/{name}">
    <inSequence>
      <dblookup>
        <connection>
          <pool>
            <password>pass</password>
            <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL</url>
            <user>user</user>
          </pool>
        </connection>
        <statement>
          <sql><![CDATA[SELECT ID, CHANNEL_NAME FROM CHANNEL where CHANNEL_NAME = ?]]></sql>
          <parameter expression="get-property('uri.var.name')" type="VARCHAR"/>
          <result column="ID" name="channel_id"/>
        </statement>
      </dblookup>
      <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('channel_id')" name="ID"/>
        <property name="State" value="after db"/>
      </log>
      <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
               {
                  "channelId":"$1"
               }
            </format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('channel_id')"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
      <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
      <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </resource>
</api>
```